# Why did Rust require macro names to have an exclamation point at the end?

Tags: rust

Why did the designers of the Rust programming language require that macro names have to end with an exclamation point?

Note that I am not saying that this design choice is wrong. I am just curious.

Comment: Also because values and macros live in different namespaces, so you need a way to dispatch between the two: you can have a function `foo` and a macro `foo` in the same scope, and both can be invoked the same way in the same context. So there needs to be a way to differentiate their lookups.

Comment: The exclamation point isn't really part of the name. A `use` declaration for a macro doesn't use the exclamation point, just the invocation.

Comment: @Masklinn I don't think this is the reason: we could decide that we don't use exclamation marks and macros don't live in a different namespace.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman that's... not a counter argument? If they live in the same namespace then you obviously don't need to dispatch between the non-different namespaces anymore.

Comment: Maybe a better fit for https://langdev.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: @JaredSmith: Thank you for that sage advice. I've posted a more elaborate question over into that site here: https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/3071/why-did-rust-require-macro-names-to-have-an-exclamation-point-at-the-end

Note also that the comments and the answers here do appear, at least as of 2023-10-28 13:59:57 USPacific time, to be guesses and speculation. Hopefully the language gurus can set me straight here. Maybe the one answer here is indeed *the* answer.  I just do not know yet.

Comment: @bgoodr Well they were *educated* guesses (and they weren't wrong after all), if you wanted a normative reference (word of god) you should have done (or shown) more research first and explicitly asked for it

Answer (score 5):

Macros are not functions. The exclamation mark at the end of them lets the user know that it's a macro, since they are so fundamentally different. The syntax inside a macro can be arbitrary; if the user doesn't know that it's a macro, they will get confused

Example:

```rust
let list = vec![0; 10];
```

Comment: …and also it lets the compiler know it's a macro I guess

Comment: @Bergi The compiler likely doesn't care, it's a convenience for humans that don't have the entire symbol table memorized like the compiler has.

Comment: @tadman It's not about the symbol table, but really about the different syntax in the macro that the parser will have to deal with. Sure, the language could have been designed and implemented differently, but then the error messages for parse errors wouldn't be as good.

Comment: @Bergi The `!` hint makes it easier to write a parser, for sure, but if that wasn't in the design Rust could still make it happen.